# Multi-Architectures and Their Binaries

Tags: 64-bit, 32-bit, libraries, multiarch, binary

Why is there a `/usr/lib` *and* a `/usr/lib32` directory but *only* a `/usr/bin` and no `/usr/bin32` directory on a AMD64 64-bit-install of Ubuntu? If or when Debian/Ubuntu start supporting multi-target-architecture binaries in their ELF's will this directory branching become unnecessary?

Answer (score 1):

Because it wouldn't be useful to install (for example) `wget` for *amd64* and *i386* on the same machine.
One of them could be first in `PATH`, and so only that one would be executed when you ran `wget`.

Installing binaries from multiple libraries at the same time is only useful for shared libraries.

Oh, also, multiarch **doesn't** use `/usr/lib32`, that's a hack used in bi-arch (which we've never really done in Debian/Ubuntu). The multiarch libraries live in `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/` for `amd64` and `/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/` for `i386`.

You can find the name of that directory by running:

```
$ dpkg-architecture -qDEB_HOST_MULTIARCH
x86_64-linux-gnu
```